# Terminal command `screen` will not split windows vertically

Tags: macos, terminal

Macs come with `screen` natively installed, but I seem to have a problem with mine. After running `screen` and creating another window (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>), the split command (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd>) won't do anything. Normally it's suppose to split the terminal **vertically** into two separate windows (typically used to edit and test in one terminal window).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you want is to <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> (split first), and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to the new region.  Now you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>c</kbd> to create a new shell in that new region.

If you want vertical split, be sure to check the version of screen that you're running.  According to this [Unix SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26786/83711), vertical split is NOT a default feature and needs to be patched in.

The TL;DR of it is: you'll need to download and compile a new screen command with the appropriate patch (or at least a newer version if the patch has been merged into the main project).

Comment: This works wonderfully, but I really want to split vertically.

Comment: Updated the answer, though I think it may disappoint you :-/

Comment: Do you know if brew has the appropriate version? Also, how should I go about uninstalling this terminal feature?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head if the brew version will help.  Not sure what you mean about "uninstalling this terminal feature," can you expand?

Comment: If I download the newer version of `screen` will it simply overwrite the current `screen` or do I need to uninstall/remove the OS X `screen` and then find a newer version and download that one?

Comment: Ah gotcha.  No need to uninstall, just make sure that the brew path for executables /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin in your PATH environment variable; this will be set in one or more of .profile .bashrc .bash_profile in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for quite a while, it turns out the Mac distro of GNU screen did not incorporate the vertial split function. You need to either patch it by yourself or wait until it is ported. (as of v4.0.6)